# Fake forking your own repo for maintainability purpose

Tags: git, github

I am not sure how to precisely describe the issue so I will use an example, say i have the following:

- `RepoA` - original repo with some base code, libs, framework, folder structure, etc
- `RepoB` - ideally a fork/branch... but can't fork your own repos and I want a separate repo, so branch doesn't work

The goal is to work on `RepoB` and be able to `merge` changes that have been made inside `RepoA` into the code, so if a new feature is developed on `RepoA` I can just merge it into the `RepoB` and continue development. Essentially it is a "branch" of a different repo.

Is this somehow possible?

I've also thought of maybe somehow using NPM to get this functionality but I am not sure at all how to/how it works with NPM, all my work on company projects would have a single repo and feature branches, so I've never encountered this problem.

#### EDIT: As per comments

The idea is to setup a repo structure with all the things that I commonly use in multiple projects, such as boilerplate, UI components, blank server, router configurations, basically create a "framework" that has no features, other than being a "work environment" that can be built upon.

Then, for each project, i'd create a specific repo and drag in the framework, for lack of the better words. But I want to be able to "merge" additional things that might get added to framework at a later point into the repo.

I do not want to branch this framework repo because I want the repositories on github to be separate. I'd be fine with somehow adding some form of dependency, or even use NPM, but I do not know how would I use NPM for this.

Comment: I fail to see how a forked repository would serve you better than a branch would in that case...

Comment: @Dellirium Maybe describe what problem you think you would have with a single repo. (@ccjmne Agreed.)

Comment: @ccjmne edited the post to reflect

Comment: At least for github you can set up a separate organization and fork from your own repos into the org.  I've used that myself while testing out some experimental CI solutions while not bogging down builds.

Comment: @AnthonySottile I've thought about it, would ideally love to have it in my repo but I am assuming that it is not doable?

Comment: tbh I didn't read the whole thing, just stopped at the "it isn't possible to fork your own repo" part

Comment: You could setup upstream to the RepoA from RepoB to push framework related improvements from RepoB to RepoA. So, 1) Create RepoB from RepoA. 2) Set fw_upstream to RepoA for RepoB. 3) When you have some FW changes, isolate them to fw_branch in RepoB and push to fw_upstream and merge to RepoA.

Comment: @MohanaRao I do not want to push from `RepoB` to `RepoA` though, not sure if I understood you correctly. I want to merge changes from `RepoA` (framework) into my `RepoB` (project)

Comment: @MohanaRao thank you, experimenting a bit with what you wrote lead me to eventually find a solution, will update the post accordingly tomorrow, 4 am... gtg now :P

Comment: Glad to know that you found a solution!

Comment: @Dellirium - don't forget to post your solution as an answer, otherwise your question will show up as unanswered, it saves other people's time if they know you have already solved your problem.

Comment: @Tony thanks for the reminder, totally forgot, been a loooong night

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some fiddling around with what Mohana Rao suggested I've managed to get what I need.

### One-time-use

We are doing all our work inside `RepoB`, say, on a master branch:

```
git remote add base <link-to-RepoA>
git checkout -b new-feature-import
git pull base master --allow-unrelated-histories
git checkout master
git merge new-feature-import
git branch -D new-feature-import
```

### Saving for future usage:

```
git remote add base <link-to-RepoA>
git fetch base
git checkout -b base-integration
git branch --set-upstream-to=base/master
git pull --allow-unrelated-histories
git checkout master
git merge base-integration
```

With the second method allowing you to switch to a branch at a later point and just do a pull to get the latest changes. Obviously any merge conflicts you'd have to resolve and obviously you should not be pushing from the `base-integration` branch back to your `RepoA` if you opt to go with this "more convenient" solution.